# how to check if several directory contain .png?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run a code but I will recive an error in a line that checks if folders contain .png file. The issue is that I don't know how to check it for several subfolder.

This is my directories
[image]

And each contain some png file
[image]

I've run the following :

```
data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Safe/training'
img = []


for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(data_dir, 'training', 'image_03')):
    if filename.endswith('.png'):
        img_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'training', 'image_03', filename)
        with Image.open(img_path) as image:
            img.append(np.array(image))




# check if images are loaded properly
if not img:
    raise ValueError("No images found in the directory")
```

And it always raise `ValueError: No images found in the directory` because file names are the folder name `0000` , `0001` and not the images they contain. how to change this to go one step further and check inside each file?

Answer (score 1):

You can browse files recursively using os.walk() like this:

```py
import os

img = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".png"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)

            print(file_path)
            
            with Image.open(img_path) as image:
                img.append(np.array(image))
                
                
if not img:
    raise ValueError("No images found in the directory")
```